# Google Geocoding API returns ZERO_RESULTS with php CURL

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-geocoder

I am trying to get the latitude and longitude from this address. The problem is that when calling the URL with curl it gives the response ZERO_RESULTS, but when calling it from the browser it gives a correct response. The certificate geocode_api exists and it is in the correct path so thats not the problem.What am i missing here? This code works just fine with other addresses

```
<?php
$url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=VIA+RISORGIMENTO,+FUMONE,+03010,+FR,+Italia";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "modules/Map/cert/geocode_api.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
if(empty($response)){
    return;
}
$response_a = json_decode($response);

echo $response;
```

Comment: I'm getting ZERO_RESULTS when entering that URL in the browser as well.

Comment: Also, I'm getting some results in browser / wget / curl when “,+FR” is removed from URL.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following requests:

1. Places autocomplete 
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=VIA%20RISORGIMENTO%2C%20FUMONE%2C%2003010%2C%20FR%2C%20Italia&key=YOUR_API_KEY
2. Geocoding request with components filters by street name, locality and country https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=route%3AVIA%20RISORGIMENTO%7Clocality%3AFUMONE%7Ccountry%3AIT&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Both return ZERO_RESULTS. That means the via Risorgimento doesn't exist in Google database.

Let's have a look at place/establishment 'Comune di Fumone, Via Risorgimento, 2, 03010 Fumone FR, Italy'

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJaUCe_RdZJRMRZMdLqZRVXnk

On the base map I can see via Covone close to this place, but any sign of via Risorgimento.

I believe you should report a missing road on maps.google.com

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088

Hope it helps!